# codemirror - empty line numbers?

Tags: javascript, codemirror, line-numbers

When you apply line numbers to code mirror, they only show if the line actually has content. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rEq3r/1/) example fiddle. It only shows line numbers 1-5.

I'm wondering if there is a configuration to instead show line numbers for the entire height? (instead of blank entries)?

I've been looking through the documentation but I can't seem to find anything on this. Any suggestions?

This is my basic configuration:

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.body, {
  value: "function myScript()\n{\n\treturn 100;\n}\n",
  mode:  "javascript",
  lineNumbers: true
});
```

Comment: why would you want that? that would mean the numbers go past the end of the document and you won't be able to tell where the doc actually ends.

Comment: you only have 5 lines of code (the last one being empty and still gets a line number), where are you expecting line numbers to be that there aren't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly workaround: just append `\n` until it starts scrolling (check `scrollTop` and `scrollHeight`).